# The unix top command in python output shows the output without spaces

Tags: python

```
Manual steps
top -b -n 1 -p `ps -eaf |grep -v grep |grep radars-lnx |awk {'print $2'}` |grep `ps -eaf |grep -v grep |grep radars-lnx |awk {'print $2'} ` |awk {'print $2" "$10"  "$11'}

output as below
root 1.0  412:24.56
```

Using python script the output comes without space's as shown below

```
import paramiko
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("10.30.64.12","22","katty","acer321")
cmd="top -b -n 1 -p `ps -eaf |grep -v grep |grep radars-lnx |awk {'print $2'}` |grep `ps -eaf |grep -v grep |grep radars-lnx |awk {'print $2'} ` |awk {'print $2" "$10"  "$11'}"
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(cmd)
#print("stdout.readlines()",stdout.readlines())
outlines=stdout.read()
print("outlines",outlines)
```

> ('outlines', 'root1.0412:32.45\n')

Comment: just tried something with regexp as shown below..print("outlines",outlines)
regnew = re.search(r'([a-z]+)([0-9]+\.[0-9]|[0-9])([0-9].*)',outlines)
print(regnew.group(1))
print(regnew.group(2))
print(regnew.group(3))
root
1.0
415:03.49
print(regnew.group(1) +" " + regnew.group(2)+" "+regnew.group(3))
o/p root 1.0 415:08.08

Comment: but was expecting the output without using regexp as manual command gives the output correct with space.